# What user to I add in SQL Server if I want my Windows Service running under LocalSystem to query the db?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, windows-services, ssms

I have a database in SQL Server and I'm trying to query it from the Windows Service I wrote and am getting the exception

> Couldn't add to db bcause The underlying provider failed on Open.

My guess is that this is because my service is running under `ServiceAccount.LocalSystem` and that doesn't have access to the db. However when I do to MyDb -> Security -> Users in SSMS and try to create a new user, I'm not sure what to put in for these values.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM in the sql server / security / logins 
and in the database users

Comment: note that i answered your question about which login to add to allow Local System to access a database. the error you mention "The underlying provider failed on Open." is due to a different cause (check the connection string ?)